# How to select row with maximum value if all values are NA in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
tt1 <- structure(list(sjlid = c("SJL1527107", "SJL1527107", "SJL1527107", 
"SJL1527107", "SJL1527107"), condition = c("Abnormal_glucose_metabolism", 
"Abnormal_glucose_metabolism", "Abnormal_glucose_metabolism", 
"Abnormal_glucose_metabolism", "Abnormal_glucose_metabolism"), 
    grade = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ageevent = c(58.8352421588442, 
    62.1366120218579, 64.4872969533648, 68.9694887341867, 70.9612695561045
    )), row.names = 72:76, class = "data.frame")
```

I need to run this code:

```
library(dplyr)
tt1 %>% group_by(condition) %>% top_n(1, grade) %>% top_n(1, ageevent)
```

This code works when there are multiple rows (like tt1), but if there are only one row (like `tt2` below), it just fails to give that particular row. For example, if I have my dataframe like this:

```
tt2 <- structure(list(sjlid = "SJL1527107", condition = "Abnormal_glucose_metabolism", 
    grade = NA, ageevent = 58.8352421588442), row.names = 72L, class = "data.frame")
```

`tt2 %>% group_by(condition) %>% top_n(1, grade) %>% top_n(1, ageevent)` returns nothing

```
# A tibble: 0 x 4
# Groups:   condition [0]
# ... with 4 variables: sjlid <chr>, condition <chr>, grade <lgl>, ageevent <dbl>
```

Instead, I want it to return this row because it's the only row there.

```
        sjlid                   condition grade         ageevent
72 SJL1527107 Abnormal_glucose_metabolism    NA 58.8352421588442
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slice_max` can be used -`top_n` is kind of deprecated in favor of `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
tt1 %>% 
  group_by(condition) %>%
  slice_max(n = 1, order_by = ageevent) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  sjlid      condition                   grade ageevent
  <chr>      <chr>                       <lgl>    <dbl>
1 SJL1527107 Abnormal_glucose_metabolism NA        71.0
```

---

It also works with `tt2` (if both columns needs to be considered)

```
tt2 %>%
  group_by(condition) %>% 
  slice_max(n = 1, order_by = pmax(ageevent, grade, na.rm = TRUE) ) %>%
  ungroup
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  sjlid      condition                   grade ageevent
  <chr>      <chr>                       <lgl>    <dbl>
1 SJL1527107 Abnormal_glucose_metabolism NA        58.8
```

If we need to prioritize, an option is also with `arrange`

```
tt2 %>%
   arrange(condition, desc(ageevent), desc(grade)) %>% 
   distinct(condition, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

---

For the `top_n`, we can use

```
tt2 %>%
   group_by(condition) %>%
   top_n(pmax(grade, ageevent, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   ungroup
Selecting by ageevent
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  sjlid      condition                   grade ageevent
  <chr>      <chr>                       <lgl>    <dbl>
1 SJL1527107 Abnormal_glucose_metabolism NA        58.8
```

Comment: Can we also get it work on `tt3 <- structure(list(sjlid = "SJL1527107", condition = "Abnormal_glucose_metabolism", 
    grade = NA, ageevent = NA), row.names = 72L, class = "data.frame")`? I want to include this row as well.

Comment: @MAPK add `1` for these cases i.e. `slice_max(n = 1, order_by = pmax(ageevent, grade, 1, na.rm = TRUE) )`

Comment: In your answer, `tt2 %>%
  group_by(condition) %>% 
  slice_max(n = 1, order_by = pmax(ageevent, grade, na.rm = TRUE) ) %>%
  ungroup` How do you priotize the max value first by grade and then ageevent? I changed it to `pmax(grade, ageevent, na.rm = TRUE) )`, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: @MAPK If you want to prioritize, do an `arrange` i.e. `tt2 %>% arrange(condition, desc(ageevent), desc(grade)) %>% distinct(condition, .keep_all = TRUE)`